# how to make table of content in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

as I am beginer please tell me how I can make toc for my web page using jQuery.
my page would look like this

====== sample Table of Content ====

> Introduction
>   |**> What is Web
>   |_**> What is JavaScript
>   Programming HTML5
>   |**> Learn HTML5
>   |**> Your First Example

Comment: Need more information about the structure of your HTML and what you want in your ToC. Is it just the heading tags? Is it a particular div that you wrap around your headings?

Comment: You should learn javascript first before trying to do jQuery ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try following **article** to create Table of Content using jQuery.

**http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/08/20/Table-of-contents-using-jQuery.aspx**

There are some plug-ins also available to do it.

[jQuery Plugin 1](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/toc)

[jQuery Plugin 2](http://fuelyourcoding.com/table-of-contents-jquery-plugin/)

[jQuery Plugin 3](http://solidgone.org/Jqtoc)

Answer (score 0):

I just released [Tocify](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.tocify.js/), a jQuery table of contents plugin that was inspired by both [Can.js](http://www.canjs.us) and [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/).